# How do I fix this nginx configuration with almost-duplicate proxied locations?

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, proxy

I have the following nginx configuration for one of my virtual servers:

```
upstream app_example_https {
  server 127.0.0.1:1340;
}

proxy_cache_path /Users/jaanus/dev/nginxcache levels=1:2 keys_zone=S3CACHE:10m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:1338;
  server_name localhost;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /Users/jaanus/dev/devHttpsCert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /Users/jaanus/dev/devHttpsKey.pem;

  location = / {

    proxy_http_version     1.1;
    proxy_set_header       Connection "";
    proxy_set_header       Host 'something.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
    proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
    proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
    proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;

    proxy_cache            S3CACHE;
    proxy_cache_valid      any 60m;
    add_header             X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

    proxy_pass             http://something.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/;

  }

  location /static/ {

    proxy_http_version     1.1;
    proxy_set_header       Connection "";
    proxy_set_header       Host 'something.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
    proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
    proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
    proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
    proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;

    proxy_cache            S3CACHE;
    proxy_cache_valid      any 60m;
    add_header             X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

    proxy_pass             http://something.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/static/;

  }


  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://app_example_https/;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

What this does in English:

There’s an nginx frontend which serves requests either from a static Amazon S3 site, or an application server.

All requests to / (site root) and /static are reverse-proxied from Amazon S3. All other requests are reverse-proxied from the application server.

Now, the problem: there are two almost identical Location blocks for the S3. This was the only way how I could make this configuration work, where two specific folders (root and /static) are served from S3, and everything else goes to the application server.

Two almost-identical blocks look dumb and are not scalable. When I add such folders, I don’t want to keep duplicating the blocks.

How do I merge the two locations into one Location block, while keeping everything working the same way?

Comment: put repeating parts into external file and `include` it.

Comment: Interesting. This would work and make it look nicer, but it would still require several Location blocks. I’d prefer something that lets me get away with just two Location blocks (one for S3 and one for the app server).

Comment: That's bad idea. Several simple locations are much easier to understand (and more efficient) than e.g. weird regexp location.

Comment: Fair enough. If you want to post this as an answer to the question, I’ll accept it in a few days unless something better comes along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put repeating part into external file and `include` it.

**amazon.inc**

```
proxy_http_version     1.1;
proxy_set_header       Connection "";
proxy_set_header       Host 'something.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;

proxy_cache            S3CACHE;
proxy_cache_valid      any 60m;
add_header             X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

proxy_pass             http://something.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
```

**your config**

```
location = / {
    include amazon.inc;
}

location /static/ {
    include amazon.inc;
}

location / {
    # proxy to you app
}
```

If you prefer to keep all in one file, you could use this trick:

```
error_page 470 = @amazon;
location = / {
    return 470;
}

location /static/ {
    return 470;
}

location @amazon {
    # proxy to amazon
}
```

You could use regexp to merge several `location`s together, but I would not recommend to do that because it's hard to read and understand and is less efficient than simple prefix locations. But, just as an example:

```
# NOT RECOMMENDED
location ~ ^/($|static/) {
    # proxy to amazon
}
```